# Как с помощью Selenium Python найти элемент?

Tags: python, selenium

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью selenium python найти и кликнуть по вот этому элементу "

```
<td style="width:10px;"><input type="image"  src="Resources/right.png" alt="Выбор"     onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gvBenefitOwners','Select$1')" style="border-width:0px;"></td>
```

в нижеприведенном коде. Таких элементов в коде довольно много и все они одинаковые. Разные только данные людей. Нужно кликнуть именно по этому элементу на определенного человека, к примеру БАКАНИНА.

```
    <tr style="color:Black;background-color:LightSteelBlue;font-weight:bold;width:15px;">
    <td style="width:10px;"><input type="image" src="Resources/right.png" alt="Выбор" 
onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gvBenefitOwners','Select$1')" 
    style="border-width:0px;"></td>
    <td>832093</td>
    <td style="width:100px;">58418488</td>
    <td>БАКАНИН</td>
    <td>АЛЕКСАНДР</td>
    <td>СЕРГЕЕВИЧ</td>
    <td>17.07.1980</td>
    <td>
    <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_cphMain_gvBenefitOwners_ctl04_cbControlBenefiter" type="checkbox" 
name="ctl00$cphMain$gvBenefitOwners$ctl04$cbControlBenefiter" 
disabled="disabled" 
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$cphMain$gvBenefitOwners$
ctl04$cbControlBenefiter\',\'\')', 0)"></span></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="color:Black;background-color:LightSteelBlue;font-
weight:bold;width:15px;">
    <td style="width:10px;"><input type="image" src="Resources/right.png" 
alt="Выбор" 
onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$gvBenefitOwners','Select$4')" 
style="border-width:0px;"></td><td>827163</td>
    <td>БОГАНОВА</td>
    <td>УСТИНЬЯ</td>
    <td>ИВАНОВНА</td>
    <td>17.10.1920</td>
    <td>
    <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_cphMain_gvBenefitOwners_ctl07_cbControlBenefiter" type="checkbox" 
name="ctl00$cphMain$gvBenefitOwners$ctl07$cbControlBenefiter" 
disabled="disabled" 
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$cphMain$gvBenefitOwners$
ctl07$cbControlBenefiter\',\'\')', 0)"></span>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: "Можете прислать ссылку на сайт? " - вопрос от @AnastasiaGergel

Comment: к сожалению нет, это закрытый сайт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе необходимо пройтись циклом по таблице, найти подходящую строку и кликнуть на необходимый элемент в этой строке.
Примерный код:

```
table_xpath = '' # путь к твоей таблице
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(table_xpath + "/tbody/tr")
match_name = False
for i in range(1, len(rows) + 1):
    columns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(table_xpath + "/tbody/tr[" + str(i) + "]/td")
    for j in range(1, len(columns) + 1):
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath(table_xpath + "/tbody/tr[" + str(i) + "]/td[" + str(j) + "]").text == 'БАКАНИНА':
            match_name = True
    if match_name:
        break
driver.find_element_by_xpath(table_xpath + "/tbody/tr[" + str(i) + "]/input").click()
```

Comment: спасибо за решение, но по xpath выдает ошибку:' raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /tbody/tr[0]/input"     говорит, нет такого элемента((  может мне нужно было что-то изменить в коде, я не поняла

Comment: Скорее всего ошибка из-за того, что я не весь путь к элементу прописал.
Надо последнюю строку заменить на:
driver.find_element_by_xpath(table_xpath + "/tbody/tr[" + str(i) + "]/td/input").click() 
Или же на:
driver.find_element_by_xpath(table_xpath + "/tbody/tr[" + str(i) + "]/td[2]/input").click()
Если потребуется точное указание в какой колонке input находится.

Answer (score 1):

В теории клик на элемент осуществяется достаточно просто: необходимо сперва найти нужный элемент одним из доступных способов (например, через указание его `id`, имени класса, пути к нему или `css selector`), затем воспользоваться атрибутом найденного кликабельного элемента `.click()`.

Все функции `.find_element_by` для нахождения элемента реализованы в Selenium с интуитивно понятными названиями. Посмотреть на набор функций можно [в документации](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

Простой способ вытащить путь к нужному элементу или его `css selector` в окне инспектируемой страницы -- правой кнопкой мыши нажать на элемент, среди прочего появятся варианты скопировать `css selector` или XTML path.

Пример реализации клика в браузере Chrome:

```
br = wb.Chrome("/Users/YOUR_PATH/chromedriver")
br.get("http://opisi.rgvarchive.ru/opisi.html")
next_page = br.find_element_by_css_selector("#example_next")
next_page.click()
```

Comment: Спасибо, я документацию читала)) у меня приведен, конкретный случай, там есть js код, никакие id, class, и уж даже css не подходят, чтобы выбрать нужную фамилию.